# Custom validator for a date inside a JSF iterable component (data table)

Tags: validation, jsf, datatable, iterable, omnifaces

I'm working with a data table with multiple objects and I need to validate the date in which one.

I was using Omnifaces 'validateMultiple' component but since it is inside the data table, the validator doesn't stop running until it reaches the last object and so, all the previous date validations are ignored.

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance for your time.